# Asynchronously check folder contents and return file paths

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I want to write a script in Node, that it checks if in given array of urls there's files and then retrieve it. I would like to make it asynchronous.

As far as I was able to develop a proper function:

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');
function getFiles(pathArr = []) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let filesArr = pathArr.filter(obj => {
      return fs.lstatSync(obj, (err, stat) => {
        if (err) {
          return false;
        }
        return stat.isFile();
      });
    });
    resolve(filesArr);
  });
}
```

But it uses `fs.lstatSync` and I want to use `fs.lstat` to be able to use it as a async method (with `.then()` usage). `pathArr` argument is an array of urls (strings) which I want to check if they're a file or folder.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');

function getFiles(pathArr = []) {
    var promises = [];
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        let filesArr = pathArr.filter(obj => {
            promises.push(fileStat(obj));
        });

        Promise.all(promises).then(function (result) {
            resolve(result);
        });
    });
}

function fileStat(obj) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        return fs.lstat(obj, (err, stat) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            resolve(stat.isFile())
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: It's almost what I was looking for. The only difference is that `fileStat` method returns true/false statements, not the urls itself like the filter method, but I think I will handle that myself, thanks!

Comment: happy to help ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of async.series, async.map, async.each. Which takes array as parameter.Refer following example which calculates total files size asynchronously.

```
let fs = require("fs");
let async = require('async');
let paths = ['./demo1.txt', './demo2.txt', './demo3.txt'];
let totalSize = 0;
let calcSize = function () {
        async.each(paths, function iterator(path, next) {
            let fileName = path.split("/");
            fs.stat(path, function (err, stat) {
                totalSize += stat.size;
                next(null);
            });
        },function(){ console.log("totalSize : "+totalSize)})
}
calcSize();
```